# single account for DocuSign API multiple client accounts for signature

Tags: docusignapi

I am wanting to use the DocuSign REST API to create an envelope for our clients. We are wanting to just create the envelope for our clients to simplify the DocuSign process. Each of our clients will have their own DocuSign account that would be separate from our API Integrator Key Account and they will share the API integrator account. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Docusign supports various authentication options to support multiple scenarios.

Based on your problem statement it looks like you are building a User Application.

See the [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#common-user) to build user applications over the DocuSign api.